# I can not connect or Oracle for ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to an Oracle 11g database using the oracle ODAC 64 with the ODT 32 bit as well. I can make the proper connection from Server Explorer for OLE DB

[image]

But then I try from the ADO.Net Entity Option I get the following, not sure why I cant get OLE DB for EF here.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to buy devart and give it a try.